# revert 'invalid' with grid doesn't return to start position with jQuery UI Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

In a nutshell, if you use draggable with a grid and set revert: 'invalid' on draggable items they don't return to exactly the same place you started dragging them from. They return to a place close to where you started dragging them...pretty weird.

This could well be a bug in UI. If so, does anyone know if there's a workaround for it?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/n2AUv/11/

Thanks!
John.

Comment: Everything behaves sensibly with just `grid` or just `revert` but all the sense goes away when you have both. The position it returns to seems random. Are we seeing the same complete nonsense?

Comment: It's what I see.. it's frustrating as it's a bit of a show stopper for my project.

Comment: I'd call it a bug and make a bug report, the current behavior doesn't make any sense at all. Could you re-parent the elements when they're dropped? That might help, the negative offsets (use your DOM inspector and you'll see them) might be confusing something.

Comment: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4696 Bug filed > 2 years ago and set to 'wontfix' - this suggests I'm at error. Any thoughts? :/

Comment: "These options won't exist in the rewrite." I have a response to that but it isn't suitable for a polite forum like SO. Is there a beta of the rewrite on github.com somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`grid` option documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-grid) says:

> Snaps the dragging **helper** to a grid, every x and y pixels.

So it looks like `grid` was designed to be used only with some kind of helper. And really, if you use `helper: "clone"` things are good: helper returns near the place of original instance and

Yes, this looks like a bug in UI.
But there's a workaround: [use helper for dragging](http://jsfiddle.net/r2JNp/6/):

```
$(".dragme").draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone",
    grid: [50,50]
});
```

This workaround introduces other weird bug: after a valid drop on droppable area helper gets destroyed and original instance exists in it's place (you can see it at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2JNp/6/)).

This bug somehow solved for `draggable` with `connectToSortable` options. Maybe it's possible to solve the bug in your case too.

Also, I suspect the whole mess is because of [this chunk of code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js#L446-454) in draggable.

Comment: @John Hunt If it helps, here is a tweak to yko's code that correctly places the dragged element in the correct place in the drop target div (using absolute positioning): http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/EBHWr/

Comment: @GregL very nice. I actually thought `drop` being triggered on any drop, not only valid. Looks like my solution combined with yours one could solve this problem. Don't you mind if I combine them together in my answer?

Comment: Not at all. It was fun to take your answer and run with it. You can't split bounties, can you? :-)

Comment: I don't know if you can split bounties, but if I can I will :)

Comment: @GregL - I'm not actually too hot with jQuery / ui, is there a way to hide the original square on your fiddle as you drag it (so it looks right)? I had a go but it ended up totally disappearing for good etc.

Comment: @GregL, than you better write your own answer and receive bounty. Somebody have to! :)

Comment: @JohnHunt talking about hiding original instance: just use `start` and `stop` events of `draggable` to hide and restore original: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q5WX/3/ Also note: this fiddle based on @GregL one. Final solution looks a bit dirty, but works.

Comment: @John Hunt: Does this update do what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/EBHWr/1/

Comment: Lol, we both came up with the same solution. :-) Great minds think alike.

Comment: @GregL, almost :) I'd like it to make copies of the object from the original squares on the screen. The idea is that you'll have a palette of items at the bottom that you can then drag to the dropzone over and over... this is v.close to that though :) Thanks!

Comment: Like this (but with snappy grid obviously..) http://examples.placona.co.uk/drag_drop