# jQuery: Draggable on Resizable Droppable: Item disappears after dropping

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable, resizable

I just googled a lot but couldn't find an answer.

I have a resizable div and want to drop something onto it. It works very well so far. But when I use the clone-helper, the item just disappears when dropped. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#resizable').droppable({

  });

$('.base').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    stack: '#resizable',
    containment: '#resizable',
    cursor: 'move',
    appendTo: '#resizable' 
  });
```

I played with appendTo, accept and everything. I just can't get it to work... Any idea is appreciated very much!

Comment: Maybe provide some of the html to? So we can see what your trying to drag/resize into which element a little better :) Maybe it doesn't dissapear, but just gets stuck in a div behind it.

Answer (score 10):

I would try adding the following to your droppable's options:

```
$('#resizable').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $.ui.ddmanager.current.cancelHelperRemoval = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We were discussing similar issue in topic [revert 'invalid' with grid doesn't return to start position with jQuery UI Draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102859/revert-invalid-with-grid-doesnt-return-to-start-position-with-jquery-ui-dragg/8133221#8133221) and @GregL offered workaround for this: http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/EBHWr/

I think this is exactly your situation. You need to define `drop` handler in `droppable`. This looks like a bug in jQuery with `draggable` and `helper: "clone"`.

Comment: If I change the droppable code of my resizable div, the draggable isn't draggable anymore... I will post to jsFiddle to make my problem clear :) thx so far!

Comment: So, thank you again - I just created the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Florian_Kratschmann/eTqZ2/1/) just uncomment the helper-line and you see my problem ...