# Javascript Grid UI - Draggable & Resizeable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, javascript-framework

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask such a question but I am looking to find a javascript component which does the following functions:

- Have an amount of columns / rows
- The grid will have several items in it, the width of the items can spread multiple columns and rows but fits in the grid
- User must be able to drag elements around but not overlapping other elements
- User must be able to resize elements in all directions but again, not overlapping other elements
- Attach to events on resize / drag in order to communicate such changes with backend

The image below depicts a visual example of what I am looking for.  In the below example, the X-axis would represent time slots while the Y-axis would represent Table Nos and hence the red blocks below are denoting:

- Table #2 allocated from 12:00 - 15:00
- Table #4 allocated from 15:00 - 17:00
- Table #6 & 7 allocated from 14:00 - 16:00

[image: Grid UI example]

Comment: @AsifMahamud - Yes I am aware about that but am looking if there is something ready off the shelf which does all the above which combines dragging & resizing, snapped to a grid and doesn't allow overlaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several researching and didn't manage to find something suitable, I just made something simple using jQueryUI as a proof of concept which can be seen on [my pen on CodePen](http://codepen.io/casasoft/pen/rkLqa) which supports the creation of a 5 x 5 grid, sample 3 'booked slots' which you can drag on the pink slots and resizeable.

Unfortunately, jQueryUI has got a bug which is quite old and have never been fixed which is [revert 'invalid' with grid doesn't return to start position with jQuery UI Draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102859/revert-invalid-with-grid-doesnt-return-to-start-position-with-jquery-ui-dragg).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it was available when you needed it, but [gridster](http://gridster.net/) seems to do everything you are after.

Comment: That sounds a very interesting option. I will take a look into it in more depth.  Thanks for your recommendation!